# OverflowError: math range error - Exponent Python

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to create a simple simulated annealing search using python, but always shown an overflow error when calculating the exponent using math.exp.

and this is my code in python:

```
import random
import math

def getF(x1, x2):
    t1 = (4 - (2.1 * (x1 ** 2) + (x1 ** 4) / 3)) * (x1 ** 2)
    t2 = x1 * x2
    t3 = (-4 + (4 * (x2 ** 2))) * (x2 ** 2)
    t = t1 + t2 + t3
    return t


def getP(dE, t):
    return math.exp((-1*dE)/t)


def getNewRandInRange(x):
    newX = x + random.randint(-5, 5)
    while (newX > 10) or (newX < -10):
        newX = x + random.randint(-5, 5)
    return newX

initState1 = random.randint(-10, 10)
initState2 = random.randint(-10, 10)

currentState1 = initState1
currentState2 = initState2

BSF = getF(currentState1, currentState2)

T = 1000
Tmin = 1

while T > Tmin:
    print("T= %f" %T)
    newState1 = getNewRandInRange(currentState1)
    newState2 = getNewRandInRange(currentState2)

    currentF = getF(currentState1, currentState2)
    newF = getF(newState1, newState2)

    print("Current X1= %f" % currentState1)
    print("Current X2= %f" % currentState2)
    print("New X1= %f" % newState1)
    print("New X2= %f" % newState2)

    dE = currentF - newF
    print ("delta E: %f" %dE)

    if dE > 0:
        currentState1 = newState1
        currentState2 = newState2
        BSF = getF(newState1, newState2)
    else:
        randNumber = random.uniform(0, 1)
        p = getP(dE, T)
        if (randNumber < p):
            currentState1 = newState1
            currentState2 = newState2

    print("BSF: %f" %BSF)
    print("\n\n\n")
    T = T * 0.9

print(BSF) #final output
```

error msg:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last): 
    return math.exp((-1*dE)/t)
OverflowError: math range error
```

I'm trying using try and catch but it will not return the exponent number and it will makes a problem with the result and also I'm trying googling but doesn't find any solution that meet my requirements.

Thank you before!

Comment: could you post the error traceback too

Comment: can you check the values of (-1*dE)/t, they might be very large or very small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> exception OverflowError

Raised when the result of an arithmetic operation is too large to be represented. This cannot occur for long integers (which would rather raise MemoryError than give up) and for most operations with plain integers, which return a long integer instead. Because of the lack of standardization of floating point exception handling in C, most floating point operations also aren’t checked.  [Ref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OverflowError)

You tried to calculate a big number (bigger than 710) and that is outside of the range of a double.

You can handle it with `try/except` like this:

```
def getP(dE, t):
    try:
        return math.exp((-1*dE)/t)
    except:
        return -1 # or anything else :D
```

You can find this comment in Python's code:

```
/*
 * For the sake of simplicity and correctness, we impose an artificial
 * limit on ndigits, the total number of hex digits in the coefficient
 * The limit is chosen to ensure that, writing exp for the exponent,
 *
 *   (1) if exp > LONG_MAX/2 then the value of the hex string is
 *   guaranteed to overflow (provided it's nonzero)
 *
 *   (2) if exp < LONG_MIN/2 then the value of the hex string is
 *   guaranteed to underflow to 0.
 *
 *   (3) if LONG_MIN/2 <= exp <= LONG_MAX/2 then there's no danger of
 *   overflow in the calculation of exp and top_exp below.
 *
 * More specifically, ndigits is assumed to satisfy the following
 * inequalities:
 *
 *   4*ndigits <= DBL_MIN_EXP - DBL_MANT_DIG - LONG_MIN/2
 *   4*ndigits <= LONG_MAX/2 + 1 - DBL_MAX_EXP
 *
 * If either of these inequalities is not satisfied, a ValueError is
 * raised.  Otherwise, write x for the value of the hex string, and
 * assume x is nonzero.  Then
 *
 *   2**(exp-4*ndigits) <= |x| < 2**(exp+4*ndigits).
 *
 * Now if exp > LONG_MAX/2 then:
 *
 *   exp - 4*ndigits >= LONG_MAX/2 + 1 - (LONG_MAX/2 + 1 - DBL_MAX_EXP)
 *                    = DBL_MAX_EXP
 *
 * so |x| >= 2**DBL_MAX_EXP, which is too large to be stored in C
 * double, so overflows.  If exp < LONG_MIN/2, then
 *
 *   exp + 4*ndigits <= LONG_MIN/2 - 1 + (
 *                      DBL_MIN_EXP - DBL_MANT_DIG - LONG_MIN/2)
 *                    = DBL_MIN_EXP - DBL_MANT_DIG - 1
 *
 * and so |x| < 2**(DBL_MIN_EXP-DBL_MANT_DIG-1), hence underflows to 0
 * when converted to a C double.
 *
 * It's easy to show that if LONG_MIN/2 <= exp <= LONG_MAX/2 then both
 * exp+4*ndigits and exp-4*ndigits are within the range of a long.
 */
```

Anyway, You can use `Decimal`:

```
import decimal
...
def getP(dE, t):
    return decimal.Decimal((-1*dE)/t).exp()
```

Comment: as said before, i can't use try and catch 'cause it will returns an unexpected number that will makes a problem (in this case -1) but can i round the number so the digit will not exceed the digit limit?

Comment: @YogiWisesa I Updated my answer ;) You can use decimal for this situation